# the contract reflected all the tiny details?

Tags: vocabulary

"Matt's job was to make sure the contract reflected all the tiny details."

What does "reflect" in this sentence mean?  contain?
What other synonyms that have the same meaning ?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary for the various meanings of 'reflect?' Have you visited our sister site [ell.se] ?

Comment: ODO: "1.2 Embody or represent (something) in a faithful or appropriate way: *schools should reflect cultural differences*"  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reflect  "1 
[transitive] to show the existence or nature of something *He said that the statement did not reflect his own views.* 
be reflected in: *Public anger is reflected in the latest opinion polls.* " http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/reflect

Answer (score 1):

It is a metaphoric usage from the core meaning that you would use with a mirror: "The mirror **reflects** the image in front of it". The implication is that one entity is a parallel of another: I have two eyes - and my mirror image has two eyes that look remarkably similar. There is a big nose on my face - and there is one in the mirror as well.

In your sentence, the intended meaning is that all the tiny details that exist in reality are also represented in the contract.

A possible near-synonymous replacement, for all the same reasons, would be "Matt's job was to make sure all the tiny details were **[faithfully] reproduced** in the contract."

Comment: Call me a quibbler, but in your profile photo your nose actually looks rather small.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Surprisingly, my profile photo does not **reflect** my actual appearance.

Comment: How strange. **Mine** is absolutely faithful to my looks in real life.